# Checking the status of an External System on Application Startup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, global-asax

We are developing an ASP.NET MVC web application that is dependent on another system for some of it's data. (The merits of this choice are outside the scope of this question)

When our web application starts up we need it to check the status of the other system. We do this by logging in to it using a HTTPCLient request.

If the system does not respond or the credentials are incorrect, then our system should not start either, and redirect the user to an Error page. If the login is successful, we grab a load of data from it, and put it into our local cache.

The problem i'm having is that the user is not directed to the error page, the are directed to our application login page instead.

Here's my Global ASAX.

```
 private bool _externalSystemAvailable;

 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AutomapperConfiguration.Configure();


        _externalSystemAvailable = ExternalSystem.Login();

    }

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication) source;

        var ctx = app.Context;

        FirstRequestInitialisation.Initialise(ctx, _externalSystemAvailable);
    }
```

I have another class based on [this](http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart/) that checks whether the application is initialised already and performs the necessary post initialisation routines. I have this class so that the check is not performed on every request.

```
public class FirstRequestInitialisation
{
    private static bool _alreadyInitialized = false;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static void Initialise(HttpContext context, bool _xternalSystemAvailable)
    {
        if (_alreadyInitialized)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_alreadyInitialized)
            {
                return;

            }
        }

        if ( !externalSystemAvailable)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/Home/Error");
        }

        _alreadyInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

the `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/Home/Error");`is being hit, but the user is not being redirected.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect user in `Application_BeginRequest`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!externalSystemAvailable)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Home/Error", false);
        Response.StatusCode = 301;
    } 
}
```

But there is problem with above code and that is by calling `Response.Redirect` you create new page request which means that event fires again and again and again and it fall into infinite loop.

I think better place for doing that is Session_Start:

```
protected void Session_Start(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session.IsNewSession && !externalSystemAvailable)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Home/Error", false);
        Response.StatusCode = 301;
    } 
}
```

Comment: The issue is fixed for now anyway

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake on my part. The Home Controller was restricted to authenticated users.